# udefined variable when using mysql_num_rows

Tags: php, mysql

I am having problems with variables. It seems like I have to always initialize $variable before using it. This is very irritating.
 $username_check= mysql_num_rows($sql_username_check); here it says Notice: Undefined variable: username_check in c://
Notice: Undefined variable: email_check in c://
I am checking for duplicate data in db. It is adding the same data unfortunatelly :(
Can someone help me with this.

```
// Database duplicate Fields Check
        $sql_username_check = mysql_query("SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE user_username='$username' LIMIT 1");
        $sql_email_check = mysql_query("SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE user_email='$email' LIMIT 1");
        if($sql_username_check != "")
            if(isset($username_check))
                $username_check= mysql_num_rows($sql_username_check);
        if($sql_email_check != "")
            if(isset($email_check))
                $email_check = mysql_num_rows($sql_email_check); 
        if ($username_check > 0){ 
            $errorMsg = "<u>ERROR:</u><br />Your User Name is already in use inside of our system. Please try another.";
        } 
        else if ($email_check > 0){ 
            $errorMsg = "<u>ERROR:</u><br />Your Email address is already in use inside our system. Please try another.";
        }
```

Comment: i used isset for variables but it is not working :(

Comment: Stop. You're using an obsolete API. Switch to MySQLi or PDO. (Someone will copy-paste the usual comment, but I don't have the markdown for it...)

Answer (score 0):

You have got some really strange code, but you can try this:

```
    $sql_username_check = mysql_query("SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE user_username='$username' LIMIT 1");
    $sql_email_check = mysql_query("SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE user_email='$email' LIMIT 1");

    if($sql_username_check)
      $username_check= mysql_num_rows($sql_username_check);

    if($sql_email_check)
      $email_check = mysql_num_rows($sql_email_check); 

    if (isset($username_check) && $username_check > 0){ 
        $errorMsg = "<u>ERROR:</u><br />Your User Name is already in use inside of our system. Please try another.";
    } else if (isset($email_check) && $email_check > 0){ 
        $errorMsg = "<u>ERROR:</u><br />Your Email address is already in use inside our system. Please try another.";
    }
```

Comment: hahaha. Thanks guys. I gave up and initialized both variables. Afterall this is the only place I use them.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to start here:

```
$sql_username_check = mysql_query("SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE user_username='$username' LIMIT 1");
$sql_email_check = mysql_query("SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE user_email='$email' LIMIT 1");
```

The function calls do not return strings, thus your comparisons below are not doing what you think they are doing.  The line causing the errors are probably these:

```
if ($username_check > 0){ 
        $errorMsg = "<u>ERROR:</u><br />Your User Name is already in use inside of our system. Please try another.";
    } 
    else if ($email_check > 0){ 
        $errorMsg = "<u>ERROR:</u><br />Your Email address is already in use inside our system. Please try another.";
    }
```

From what I read from your example I can;t think of any way in which `$username_check` and `$email_check` would be set here such that you wouldn't get those notices).

What you really need to do is to understand how to work with result sets from the database, including database error handling.

While you are reading up on that, you should go ahead and dump your usage of `mysql_*` functions as they are deprecated and learn using `mysqli` or `PDO` which are the most popular of the preferred database libraries to use in PHP.

Comment: I am sorry guys but I am still a student. Noone teaches me about good or bad practices. I learn from people like you what to do. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: @Angelina No problem.  I would suggest looking at mysqli since it is most similar to `mysql_*` syntax (if you use it in a procedural fashion anyways... I would actually suggest trying to learn to work with it or PDO in an object-oriented fashion).  Make sure that you understand what the return values for each function/method call are from the documentation.  If you even look at that `mysql_query` documentation, you will realize that trying to compare the function result against an empty string is not what you should be doing.

Comment: @Angelina Also make sure that you provide code branches for all possibilities of the function call.. For example on `mysql_query` using a SELECT statement, the possible function results are false (there was an error) or a resource containing the result set.  You should have code to handle the `false` case as well as the `resource` case.

Comment: @Angelina One final thing of note, it is considered bad practice from a security perspectice to tell users if specific usernames/emails in the system exist on login attempt.  Having this knowledge would greatly increase a potential attacker's ability to exploit the system as you have now confirmed half of the information needed to login.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($username_check))
```

this is used before `$username_check` is assigned, thats why notice is there.

try code like this:

```
$sql_username_check = mysql_query("SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE user_username='$username' LIMIT 1");
        $sql_email_check = mysql_query("SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE user_email='$email' LIMIT 1");
        if($sql_username_check != "")
            $username_check= mysql_num_rows($sql_username_check);
        if($sql_email_check != "")
            $email_check = mysql_num_rows($sql_email_check); 
        if ($username_check > 0){ 
            $errorMsg = "<u>ERROR:</u><br />Your User Name is already in use inside of our system. Please try another.";
        } 
        else if ($email_check > 0){ 
            $errorMsg = "<u>ERROR:</u><br />Your Email address is already in use inside our system. Please try another.";
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

you need to adjust error reporting settings in PHP.  For example like this:

```
error_reporting (E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT);
```

Comment: Terrible advice.  The code should actually be fixed not to have these notices.  They are there for a reason and oftentimes arise from bad coding practice and/or bad code execution paths. Just turning off the errors won't make the code work correctly.